# Can different single sign on be configured for internal org and experience cloud portal?

Tags: single-sign-on, experience-cloud

Can different single sign on authentication providers be configured for internal users and experience cloud portal users?

I assume we can have multiple SAML SSO authentication providers setup but how do we configure that one should be used for internal users and the other one for external users so that external SSO AuthProvider is not available for internal users and the internal users SSO AuthProvider is not available for the external users?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can but have never done it myself. Salesforce supports multiple IDPs.

For configuring SSO for your Experience Cloud site - From within the site's administrator/settings page, you should be able to pick which SSO option appears on the site's login page. This is independent of your Salesforce orgs configuration.